# Can I copy archlinux installation to another computer?

Tags: arch-linux, cloning

I want to get an archlinux system with the same packages, settings, etc. on another computer. Can I do it by creating partitions on another computer, mounting them, copying the whole filesystem, editing fstab, crypttab, grub config, installing grub, generating new kernel? Is there anything else I will need to do?

Comment: You may have problems with your `fstab` if it uses UUIDs of the original machine's drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about crypttab, never encrypted the system myself, but otherwise it should work, mind the network settings and hostname too if they're going to be on the same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but I would make a recommendation against it.

As other users have said, you will have troubles with `fstab` if it uses UUIDs or labels (if the labels differ), you will have trouble with crypttab (and with encrypted partitions generally).

Instead, I would recommend generating a list of packages that you have on your machine right now (something to the affect of `pacman -Qq`; see `man pacman` for more). In addition, if you do not keep a repository of your dotfiles / configurations, now seems like a great time to start!

Then, you can run the new archlinux install setting up your encrypted partitions and boot sequence and when it comes time to `pacstrap`, you can `cat` your package list for it to use. All you have to do then is to replicate your configurations from your repository and you should be all-set.

This is more work than just copying everything over, but it will be more consistent, and far more reliable.

If you find yourself often replicating a system, might I recommend scripting your own Archlinux installation?

*Note*: I do *not* think you should use any of the pre-made archlinux installation scripts. However, once you know what kind of system you want, and you're familiar with the basics, scripting your own install can be a fun learning opportunity and can simplify this process for you.